# How to find physical_device_name on backup by extending great query from Ozar?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Found this on an older blog post at BrentOzar.com:

```
SELECT  d.name, MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS last_backup_finish_date
FROM    master.sys.databases d WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.name = b.database_name AND b.type = 'D'
WHERE d.name <> 'tempdb'
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY 2
```

Pretty great query!

Question: is there is an elegant way to join on `msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily` and return the `physical_device_name` for those databases that DO have recent backups? Result set should still return the ones without backups.

My attempts thus far stink :-)

Link to blog post:
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-talk-your-boss-about-world-backup-day/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH backups (DatabaseName, LastBackupFinishDate)
AS
(   
    SELECT d.name AS DatabaseName, MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS LastBackupFinishDate 
    FROM master.sys.databases d WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON d.name = b.database_name AND b.type = 'D' 
    WHERE d.name <> 'tempdb' 
    GROUP BY d.name
)
SELECT  
    b.DatabaseName,
    b.LastBackupFinishDate,
    bmf.physical_device_name
FROM backups b 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON b.DatabaseName = bs.database_name
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset bms ON bs.media_set_id = bms.media_set_id
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf ON bms.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the replies.  Here is what I've settled on (Tara's query with Nic's logic).  Just added LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON b.DatabaseName = bs.database_name AND b.LastBackupFinishDate = bs.backup_finish_date to above.  It narrows the result set down to the most recent backups.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 0):

This might need a tweak or two, but try this for starters:

```
SELECT  d.name, MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS last_backup_finish_date, max(physical_device_name) AS physical_device_name
FROM    master.sys.databases d WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.name = b.database_name AND b.type = 'D'
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.media_set_id = c.media_set_id 
WHERE d.name <> 'tempdb'
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need...

```
;WITH cteMaxBackups AS (SELECT  d.name, MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS last_backup_finish_date
FROM    master.sys.databases d WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.name = b.database_name AND b.type = 'D'
WHERE d.name <> 'tempdb'
GROUP BY d.name
)
select c.name, c.last_backup_finish_date, m.physical_device_name from cteMaxBackups c 
    left join msdb.dbo.backupset b on c.name = b.database_name and c.last_backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date
    left join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m on b.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
order by last_backup_finish_date desc
```